# how to check the duplicate entry in sql

Tags: c#, sql-server

Design of SQL Table **Users:**

```
Columns:
ID(Primary Key),
Name,
Age,
Zip.
```

I am displaying a grid view onto the asp.net application with the above table details which i am able to do now.Right now i am displaying only Name,age,zip on to the gridview.There is a form below the gridview where user can enter the data and save back to the DB.Here i am able to enter name,age,zip to the database and i am able to see the changes in the gridview.

So when i enter a duplicate name its not saving to the database as expected,at this point i have to show some thing to the user that the **name** already exists .

Here is my code in c#:

```
try
{
    param[0] = new SqlParameter("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    param[0].Value = txtName.Text;
    param[1] = new SqlParameter("@Age", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    param[1].Value = txtAge.Text;
    param[2] = new SqlParameter("@Zip", SqlDbType.int);
    param[2].Value = txtZip.Text;
    DBHelper helper = new DBHelper();
    helper.ExecuteNonQuery(CommandType.StoredProcedure, "Add_Users", param);
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

}
```

I am expecting an sql exception in the above code where i am planning to notify the user .But i am unable to get any exception .

Can some one suggest where i am missing the catch here.

**I just want to notify the user that the name is already taken eventually.**

Comment: have you put a unique constraint on the Name field in the database?

Comment: All you need is a unique constraint on the field `Name` within your database.

Comment: @MrGomez its not saving duplicate names into the Database.I just want to check the user name exists before the user inserts same name and have to display the user.

Comment: @linkerro no there is no unique constraint on the name field.

Comment: @Macnique That's actually not the issue. The issue is you're expecting an exception when your NonQuery is evaluated. Setting a unique constraint will raise one such exception, because the query would violate the constraints of your database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using exceptions is a bad design in this case. This is not an error, but a predictable behaviour of your program.

One of the easiest ways to solve the problem is doing a select at the end of the Add_Users stored procedure that returns 1 or 0, depending on the success or failure, and using ExecuteScalar insead of ExecuteNonQuery to get the result.

You can also use a return in the stored procedure, and take back that value (geenrally as a special output parameter), but I don't know if the DbHelper allows you to do so.

Comment: Ifyou want to use the return value, you need a SqlParameter with Direction=ReturnValue.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to post your SQL code for "Add_Users".

I would think about doing a validation step rather than attempting to add it.  So have one Stored Procedure for validation were you check the number of rows that contain the name you are trying to add.  If the count is zero then proceed with the add.  If there are records with that name then display a message to the user.

Answer (score 0):

In your DBHelper use count to determine if your db should commit or not :

```
 int count = SELECT COUNT(column_name) FROM table_name
```

and return it to your method which can then test it (instead of using Try/Catch)

```
if (helper.ExecuteNonQuery(CommandType.StoredProcedure, "Add_Users", param) >0))
   {
       // Show Error
   }else 
   {
       // all ok
   }
```

Comment: This depends on the structure of the SP. If it's a single query, getting the count of affected rows is OK. If there are several queries this can fail, unless you use SET NOCOUNT ON/OFF in the sp.